# YouTube livestream chat replay not working

Tags: youtube

I want to display my YouTube Livestream chat replay.

This is the code I tried:

```
<div id="live-stream-container">

<iframe width="835" height="505" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" ></iframe>

<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="505" src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=VIDEO_ID&embed_domain=MY_DOMAIN.com"></iframe>

</div>
```

*ps: I have input the correct video ID in VIDEO_ID & MY_DOMAIN is correctly input.*

When I run this code, I am able to successfully watch my Livestream again. But, the Livestream chat replay does not appear.

It shows: "Chat is disabled for this Livestream."

I further went to research on Google and set this:

- Allowed embedding in YouTube studio
- Made it 'Not for kids'
- No, don't restrict my video to viewers over 18 only
- Allowed all comments
- Livechat replay is enabled

But my code still doesn't work, it keeps showing 'Chat is disabled for this Livestream '.

*ps: The Livestream ended about 20 hours ago, so the video has been processed.*

Can someone guide me in the right direction to display my 'Live chat Replay'?

Comment: `The Livestream ended about 20 hours ago, so the video has been processed.` = I guess this is the problem. I tried with another live chat and the same message appears: `Chat is disabled for this Livestream`; however, if I try with a *current* live video - [example](https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=j3CuzN8rwV8) - I can get the live chat. If you have more questions, I suggest to keep looking for other questions and answers here on Stack Overflow or post a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) - best of luck.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Thank you for your response :) Yeah, we have tried it many times and keep getting the 'Chat is disabled..' message when the stream has ended. While the stream is playing, there is no issue. I wish they would allow replays on websites.